I have Written the WebView Application Code With Kotlinle, But My Site Does Not Load Properly
I wrote a webview application code for my site using Kotlin, everything is running smoothly, but it loads my site incorrectly. I wonder which settings are missing. I am adding my code below. I would be very happy if you could help me.
package com.shareworld.android

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import com.vorlonsoft.android.rate.AppRate
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
import com.google.firebase.analytics.ktx.analytics
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var wb_webView: WebView? = null

    private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics

        setUpUI()
        webViewSetup()
        setUpAppRate()

        val defaultSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val onboardingWasPresented = defaultSharedPreferences.getBoolean("tutorial", false)

        if (shouldShowOnboarding && !onboardingWasPresented) {
            showOnboarding()
        }
    }

    private fun setUpUI() {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_NeoWeb)
        try {
            this.supportActionBar?.hide()
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {}
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        wb_webView = findViewById(com.shareworld.android.R.id.wb_webView)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun webViewSetup() {
    wb_webView?.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    wb_webView?.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    wb_webView?.apply {
        loadUrl(websiteUrl)
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    }
}

    private fun setUpAppRate() {
        AppRate.with(this).monitor()
        AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this)
    }

    private fun showOnboarding() {
        val intent = Intent(this, IntroActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (wb_webView?.canGoBack() == true) {
            wb_webView?.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}


If you look at the image, I tried it in different webview codes where password and login are intertwined, it worked without any problems, the only code I wrote myself, the site loads like this for some reason.
image
It's loading with such problems because I didn't add a few settings in the wb_webView?.apply section, don't you think?
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun webViewSetup() {
    wb_webView?.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    wb_webView?.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    wb_webView?.apply {
        loadUrl(websiteUrl)
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    }
}


Is there no one in the huge forum who can help?

can you post the website link?

@JemoMgebrishvili https://shareworld.vercel.app

Try to call loadUrl after the webView setup will be completed
    fun setup() {
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)

      val webSettings = webView.settings
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         webSettings.safeBrowsingEnabled = true
      }
      webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
      // Enable caching
      webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
      webSettings.databaseEnabled = true
      webSettings.allowFileAccess = true

      webView.loadUrl("https://shareworld.vercel.app/sign-in")
   }


